# Does the enhanced push format prevent from getting disconnected by apple?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

When pushing to all my devices (18k) via enhanced push notification, I have to run the feedback-service and remove the invalid tokens to prevent apple disconnecting my stream. When testing, I noticed that although the first token was invalid (told by the feedback-service), the message was nonetheless delivered to the other testing devices. Before using the enhanced push format, the connection stopped and did not deliver to anybody after the invalid token. Does the enhanced push format prevent from getting disconnected? Or does apple only need some time before recognizing an invalid token and just stop a few tokens after that invalid one?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple stops processing messages when you send a wrong device id, also when using the enhanced format. At least that is what I noticed after sending a device id from a debug version of my app. I did get back the 6-bytes message indicating the error, but no data for further messages could be sent though the SSL socket after that.

From the documentation I also thought Apple would continue processing if you use the Enhanced Format, but that is not so.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I also noticed that apple only disconnects you when trying to push to a "bad" device token. If you try to push to a token which has been reported by the feedback-service, you won't get disconnected, although you should not keep that token as active after a few attempts.